# How to use IF ELSE with ON CONFLICT clause in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I have an airflow job upserting the columns of my table on daily basis via INSERT ON CONFLICT statement. The table contains a field `updated_mode` of type enum which is set to **automatic** when the row is inserted/updated by job or **manual** if's done manually.
Now, I want my job to update rows only if `updated_mode` is set to **automatic**. How can I do that?

Basically, I want to do something like:

```
Insert into table (data) values (data) on conflict (fields) if updated_mode=automatic set data=excluded.data else do nothing
```

Answer (score 6):

You need `WHERE` clause in `ON CONFLICT`.

```sql
INSERT INTO table_data 
VALUES (data) 
  ON CONFLICT (fields) 
  DO UPDATE SET  data=excluded.data 
  WHERE EXCLUDED.updated_mode='automatic'
```

Take a look at db fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwRzRSFaJx4KDMYn2GEXTe/1

Answer (score 3):

You should use the regular WHERE condition. The magic EXCLUDEED RECORD will contain existing confliting record. Something like that :

```
 Insert into table (data) values (data) 
 on conflict (fields) do update 
   set data=excluded.data 
 WHERE updated_mode=automatic 
   and fields = EXCLUDEED.fields
```

I assume that *fields* is the conflicting field and table name is *data*

Comment: 'OLD' - you mean 'EXCLUDED'? PG 13 does not accepts 'OLD' in 'ON CONFLICT' as I see

Comment: The second check `fields = EXCLUDEED.fields` is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/14.0/

> - Allow column names in the WHERE clause of ON CONFLICT to be table-qualified (Tom Lane)

Now You can more easily reference **excluded** column names and the original table columns.
setup the table.

```
create table test101(id bigint primary key, field1 text, update_mode boolean);
insert into test101 values (1,'a', TRUE);
insert into test101 values (2 ,'b', false);
```

**excluded** refer to the part you want to insert.

```
--this one will insert.
insert into  test101(id, field1,update_mode) 
    values(1,'asdf', TRUE)
on conflict (id) 
do update set
field1 = excluded.field1
WHERE 
    excluded.update_mode= test101.update_mode;
```

---

```
--this will not insert
insert into  test101(id, field1,update_mode)
values(2,'asdf', TRUE)
on conflict (id) 
do update set
field1 = excluded.field1
WHERE 
excluded.update_mode= test101.update_mode;
```